# How to make the URL shorter using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the my URL shorter to access my HTML pages from different folders.

My folder structure is:

#### ```
   My Project
     -Output
     -Files
        -CSS
        -JS
        -HTML
```

When I am trying to access the files from HTML folder, I need to write complete URL in browser.
eg. http:// Coder:8055/**Files/HTML/Login.html**

but, I want to use URL: http:// Coder:8055/**Login.html**
with same folder structure. This is same problem with showing other HTML files to access from the folder structure.
I want to keep same folder structure and show shorter URL in browser.
How do I create this type of URL to access my all HTML files...?

Comment: Server side rewrite rules

Comment: or make your virtualhost be pointed to myProject/Files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
history.pushState('', '', '/login.html');
```

Comment: Server side rewrite rules

Answer (score 0):

**If you use .Net**, you can use httphandlers

in web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.html" verb="*" type="WebSite.HttpExtensions.PageHandler" validate="false" />
   </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Then you could do something like this (I use VB):

```
Namespace HttpExtensions
    Public Class PageHandler
        Implements IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState

        Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean _
        Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
            Get
                Return False
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) _
        Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

            Dim strURL As String = context.Request.ServerVariables("URL")

            Dim newURL As String = strURL.replace("/part/of/path", "")

            context.Server.Transfer(newURL, True)

        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Basically any .html extension you go to in the website URL will fire us into that PageHandler class. The server.transfer will load your "nasty" URL page into the "nice" URL page. You have to make sure the "type" field in web.config matches the path to the class you setup. In this instance the root namespace is simply "WebSite".

---

**If you want to just modify the URL with JavaScript**, you can use [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

example:

```
history.pushState('', '', '/login.html');
```

The caveat of this is that it will [only work from IE10 onwards](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).